# Redirecting the cassandra shell output to file

Tags: linux, cassandra, linux-kernel, cassandra-3.0

It is a LINUX question,

I have a Cassandra cluster with 6 nodes and I am using the cqlsh.
I have enabled the TRACING ON feature , So on any READ / WRITE it prints too much lines of information which actually I need. So I need to redirect all the informations to a file which I perform inside cqlsh.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Could somebody explain why the two downvotes for hell sake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside cqlsh, once the tracing is turned on, you can use the CAPTURE command to redirect the your sql or command output to a file

Example: `CAPTURE 'output.txt'` -- output of the sql executed after this command gets captured into output.txt file

In case if you would like to redirect the SQL output to a file from outside of cqlsh

`./cqlsh -e'select * from keyspaceName.tableName' > fileName.txt -- hostname`